# Filtering Combobox choices

Tags: c#, wpf, linq

I have a data grid containing

```
       Client Name    Account Type   Date Created
```

I also have 3 comboboxes which when an item is clicked it calls the `SelectedIndexChanged` function which is then reflected in the data grid by moving to a matching occurance . However multiple clients can have the same account type so I want my combobox to work so that if an account type is clicked it calls the selectedIndexChanged function such that it moves to a row where the account type is correct but the Client name is also contained in that row.

As I'm new to using comboboxes in this way I'm not sure how to code this up. I've looked on various forums but none of them seem to have encountered this problem

Comment: How about showing us your code attempts so far? Please *at least* show your `SelectedIndexChanged` method.

Comment: @Sheridan my selected index changed has no code its just   private void comboBox7_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
         
        }

Comment: @sheridan that code just brings the cursor to the selected item

Comment: You said 'when an item is clicked it calls the `SelectedIndexChanged` function which is then reflected in the data grid by moving to a matching occurance'... please show how it does this. Also, are you using MVVM, or writing in the code behind?

Comment: @Sheridan I'm not sure how it does it , the function i showed there just does it theres no other code included , when the combobox calls that function it moves the datagrid cursor to the selected item

Comment: Dude, if you don't know how or can't work out how the code in front of you works, then good luck.

Comment: @Sheridan well there is no code it just works , I've searched forums and can't find out how it works

Comment: Buddy in my personal opinion, if you are going to write WPF, then you *really* need to learn how to write WPF. You don't learn by asking individual questions in a forum, you learn by reading hundreds of pages of books and online articles... *then* you come back to the forums to 'fill in' little gaps in your knowledge by asking individual questions. Anyone that tries to help you here would probably get trapped by a continuous series of further questions as can already be seen in these comments. I hope I have not appeared rude or offended you.